# how can I add a percentage to an array of salaries with a for in loop using swift

Tags: swift, for-in-loop

I have done this using a repeat while loop and it ran. How can I do this with a for in loop

```
var salaries = [45000.0, 100000.0, 54000.0, 20000.0]
var i = 0
repeat {
    salaries[i] = salaries[i] + (salaries[i] * 0.1) 
    i += 1
} while (i < salaries.count)

print(salaries)
```

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using higher order function map

```
var salaries = [45000.0, 100000.0, 54000.0, 20000.0]
salaries = salaries.map {$0 + ($0 * 0.1)}

print(salaries)
```

also do it using for in loop

```
var salaries = [45000.0, 100000.0, 54000.0, 20000.0]


for (index,salary) in salaries.enumerated() {
    
    salaries[index] = salary + (salary * 0.1)
    
}
print(salaries)
```

Comment: please upvote as well if it helps